# What are the names of the following classes of topological spaces?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

1. The closure of any countable is compact.
2. The closure of any countable is sequentially compact.
3. The closure of any countable is pseudocompact.
4. The closure of any countable is a metric compact set.

Answer (score 3):

For (1), [$\omega$ bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-bounded_space).

I'm unaware of names for the other concepts.